# What is the value after the comma in a JavaScript array literal definition?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I have been watching a video of a conference (See: [Good JavaScript Habits for C# Developers](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN08) at 13:23 in the video). The presenter has been discussing best practices in JavaScript. One of the tips he gives is to use object literal declarations which is something I am familiar with.

However, in the code he is using he declares an array using object literal notation like so:

```
var myArray = [], name;
```

I have never seen this before. I am used to the `var myArray = []` part of the declaration but what is the second `name` value after the comma? The presenter never discusses it and I can't find any other examples of this practice. Could someone please explain what this does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is chaining variables. It's the same as doing this.

```
var myArray = [];
var name;
```

You are simply saving space by defining your variables in one line.

They don't have to be on one line either.

```
var myArray = [],
    name;
```

Comment: No need to feel like a dummy. It can definitely be confusing if you don't know what you are looking at. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply declaration of two variables: `myArray` initialized to an empty array and `name` which isn't initialized.

Note that `var` may be followed by a **list** of variable declarations each with an optional initializer. See section 12.2 of [ECMA standard 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) which defines the syntax as

> *VariableStatement* :
>   **var** *VariableDeclarationList* ;

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll be sure to check this out.